# Each row has the same random number being inserted

Tags: php, numbers

I'm looking to insert random numbers into each column in a database.

The issue that is occuring is that each column for some reason has the same random generated value being passed inside.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $targScore = 3;
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $target = 3; // The target number the sequence is adding up to
    $n = 4; // Max numbers within sequence
    
    while ($n) {
        if (1 < $n--) {
            $addend = rand(0, $target - ($n - 1));
            $target -= $addend;
            $num[] = $addend;
        } else {
            $num[] = $target;
        }
    }

    /* Rows to update */
    /* Output looks like:
        [0] = 1
        [1] = 2
        [0] = 0
        [0] = 1
    */
    $changeScore = "UPDATE players SET doja='$num[0]' WHERE score='$targScore'";
    $conn->query($changeScore);

    $changeScore = "UPDATE players SET 7acres='$num[1]' WHERE score='$targScore'";
    $conn->query($changeScore);

    $changeScore = "UPDATE players SET tweed='$num[2]' WHERE score='$targScore'";
    $conn->query($changeScore);

    $changeScore = "UPDATE players SET bickel='$num[3]' WHERE score='$targScore'";
    $conn->query($changeScore);
  }
}
```

The data looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mQMO.jpg

What I need is that each loop, it will run the randomizer again but change the numbers its inserting so that each row will have different numbers.

Comment: You seem to update all rows, where the score is the same, with the same random numbers. In other words, your update queries do not identify an single row. Apart from that, filling a database with random numbers seems utterly pointless.

Comment: "Apart from that, filling a database with random numbers seems utterly pointless." Plenty of use cases for random number in a DB :).  That's also why there's a function in MySQL that does it all for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: @Robbie Sure there are certainly cases when having a random number is useful, but storing random numbers in a database? If you put random numbers in, you get random numbers out. Why put them in, in that case? Nevertheless I said that it "seems" pointless, acknowledging that there might be a reason. For instance if you want a repeatable set of random numbers.

Comment: You have 1 million items that you want to allocate uniquely and randomly. A relational DB is the best way of gating the distribution to enforce that uniqueness. Give each item and ID, randomly select a number and hope it's not allocated - will take take forever. Select all the non-allocated numbers and repeat (hoping that things don't change from pull). Or just allocate a random number, and select the item with the lowest random number that not been allocated - super fast, no messing, and combined with an "update" (gated on "not already updated" or appropriate index) guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: There are other strategies (put everything into a REDIS list or a queue system, and pull the top item, for example). But if you already have stuff in the DB, use the power of the DB you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get a list of all the rows that meet the `score` condition. Then you have to update them one by one, so you can set different random values in each.

```
$select_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM players WHERE score = ?");
$select_stmt->bind_param("i", $targScore);
$select_stmt->execute();
$res = $select_stmt->get_result();
$update_stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE players SET doja = ?, 7acres = ?, tweed = ?, bickel = ? WHERE id = ?");
$update_stmt->bind_param("iiiii", $doja, $acres, $tweed, $bickel, $id);

$target = 3;

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $n = 4;
    $num = [];
    while ($n) {
        if (1 < $n--) {
            $addend = rand(0, $target - ($n - 1));
            $target -= $addend;
            $num[] = $addend;
        } else {
            $num[] = $target;
        }
    }
    [$doja, $acres, $tweed, $bickel] = $num;
    $id = $row['id'];
    $update_stmt->execute();
}
```

There's also no need to use four `UPDATE` statements to update 4 columns in the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a rand() function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

(Note the warning that it's not perfectly random / security secure, but nor is PHPs `rand()`).

If you do not need to know what the values are, you can simply do `UPDATE myCol=FLOOR(RAND() * 200) WHERE myConditionalField=MyCondition`

This will allocate a random number from 0 to 199; examples in the MySQL manual (linked above) as to how to set a range, e.g. `FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5))` gives an integer from 7 to 11.